# Glossaries links with non-latin labels in LuaLaTeX refer to wrong place

Tags: hyperref, luatex, pdf, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I want to make a glossary with `glossaries-extra` package and use Cyrillic characters as entries labels. Everything works fine with `XeLaTeX`. Clickable links refer to exact glossary entry. But in `LuaLaTeX` links doesn't work properly. They refer to wrong place.
Entries with Latin link works fine in every case.
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}  
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{язык}{ name={язык},
                         sort=\lowercase{язык},
                         description={Система общения людей.}}

\newglossaryentry{компьютер}{ name={компьютер},
                              sort=\lowercase{компьютер},
                              description={Вычислительная машина.}}

\makeglossaries[main]

\begin{document}

    \section*{Словарь}

    \printglossary[style=list,title={}]

    \forallglossaries{\thistype}{\section{Glossary `\thistype'}
    \forglsentries[\thistype]{\thislabel}{\gls{\thislabel}. }}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get right links in pdf with LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Interestingly it works for me if I use ASCII-only labels, i.e. `\newglossaryentry{jazik}{...}` & `\newglossaryentry{komputer}{...}`

Comment: @moewe Yes, with ASCII-only labels it works for me too. But I need Cyrillic labels

Comment: Ah bummer, since the labels are only used as internal identifiers and never exposed in the document, I thought you could be OK with using ASCII-only labels. That said, since LuaLaTeX is supposed to be a Unicode engine I would expect things to work with Cyrillic as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Ulrike Fischer described the problem is that non-ASCII characters are dropped by `\pdf@escapestring`. To avoid this, you can change `\pdf@escapestring` to encode Unicode characters in UTF-8:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}  
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{язык}{ name={язык},
                         sort=\lowercase{язык},
                         description={Система общения людей.}}

\newglossaryentry{компьютер}{ name={компьютер},
                              sort=\lowercase{компьютер},
                              description={Вычислительная машина.}}

\makeglossaries[main]

\makeatletter
\long\def\pdf@escapestring#1{%
\directlua0{%
 oberdiek.pdftexcmds.escapestring("\luaescapestring{#1}")% Almost like the original one, just omit "byte" to keep all characters.
}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \section*{Словарь}

    \printglossary[style=list,title={}]

    \forallglossaries{\thistype}{\section{Glossary `\thistype'}
    \forglsentries[\thistype]{\thislabel}{\gls{\thislabel}. }}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will have to check if this always gives a valid pdf string. But if yes, this should probably be implemented.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am quite sure that it always gives a valid PDF string. (It corresponds to a valid PDFDocEncoding string, at least if U+7F=Delete is not used, because 0x7f is undefined for PDFDocEncoding) But it does _not_ generate a valid encoding of the passed string, because PDF only accepts PDFDocEncodung and UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger, this is not quite right, because if there is any character higher then 255 then all the characters must be converted to pdf UTF16-BE BOM string prefixed with `\376\377`. Eg.  `\pdf@escapestring{1ч}` you'll get  `1\321\207` but should be `\376\377\0001\004\107`. This string will be shown in pdf correctly.

Comment: @Linuxss That's mostly right when you care about the name of the links, but here the only real requirement is that they are unique identifiers. This approach gives unique identifiers, even though decoding them gives a random set of symbols instead of a useful string. But since you normally never see them in the first place, that's not an issue.

Comment: if so, I agree.

Answer (score 10):

Not a solution but an explanation. The problem is hyperref. hyperref uses with lualatex `\pdf@escapestring` to convert the name to something that can be safely used as a destination in the pdf. But the current implementation of `\pdf@escapestring` handles only ascii, everything else is simply dropped. And this means that glossaries creates for the two entries the same destination `glo:` On the terminal you can see the warning

```
 warning  (pdf backend): ignoring duplicate destination with the name 'glo:'
```

when trying this document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter 
\pdf@escapestring {glo:компьютер}

\pdf@escapestring {glo:язык}


\hypertarget{glo:компьютер}{blub}

\hypertarget{glo:язык}{bla}


\end{document}
```